# SailsJS with EJS return view don't render

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Just wondering how can I instead of rendering a view I can return the html and store it in a variable.

I've seen:

res.view()

but that just renders the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `res.render`.  It takes the view, options and a callback:

```
res.render('home/index', {title: 'My View'}, function(err, result) {
  // Result will have the rendered view HTML
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's Express underneath Sails `res.render` should work.

See [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) for the signature.